# Duplicate key in YAML configuaration file

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

I have the following in YAML:

```
key1
  key2: "value"

key1
  key2
    key3: "value2"
```

Get exception duplicate key `key1`.

```
Caused by: org.yaml.snakeyaml.parser.ParserException: while parsing MappingNode
```

Tried various combinations but was unable to parse it correctly.

Comment: You may instruct SnakeYAML to allow duplicate keys.

Answer (score 13):

Your YAML is syntactically invalid, but I am assuming it actually looks like this:

```
key1:
  key2: "value"

key1:
  key2:
    key3: "value2"
```

Your error is that `key1` is used two times as mapping key in the root node. This is illegal as per [YAML spec](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044):

> The content of a mapping node is an unordered set of key: value node pairs, with the restriction that each of the keys is unique.

The solution is to make all keys of the same mapping unique:

```
key11:
  key2: "value"

key12:
  key2:
    key3: "value2"
```

Comment: cannot make te keys unique due to some requirement constraints

Answer (score 11):

I too faced the same issue. Then it struck on me! The answer is simple.
From

```
mapping:
  refresh:
    schedule:
      frequency:
        milli: 86400000
mapping:
  refresh:
    schedule:
      initial:
        delay:
          ms: 30000
```

to

```
mapping:
  refresh:
    schedule:
      frequency:
        milli: 86400000
      initial:
        delay:
          ms: 30000
```

Answer (score -1):

so below simple solution worked for me.
Basically, in the first scenario 'server' keyword came as a separate structure
in the 2d scenario 'server' keyword came as child structure.
I simply did a small indentation and it worked.

Before :->

server:
port: 8761

eureka:
client:
registerWithEureka: false
fetchRegistry: false

server :
waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: false

---

After :->
server:
port: 8761

eureka:
client:
registerWithEureka: false
fetchRegistry: false
server :
waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: false

Comment: Use code format if you mean to show indentation and hierarchy.

Answer (score -3):

You may fix it like this:

```yaml
key1
  key2: "value"
  key2.key3: "value2"
```