# How to dump a non dictionary python object to YAML

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I'm trying to write the yaml config file for the ROS2 domain bridge from a python script. At the end it should like this:

```
name: ol_bridge
topics:
  simulation/odometry:
    type: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    from_domain: 88
    to_domain: 40
    remap: simulation/odom_88

  simulation/odometry:
    type: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    from_domain: 89
    to_domain: 40
    remap: simulation/odom_89
```

I need to fill the config automatically with the values for `from_domain` and `to_domain`. I tried to use `yaml.dump()` and create a nested dictionary using dict comprehension with the corresponding structure. I think it failed because I cannot use the same key (`simulation/odometry`) twice.

Comment: Doesn't the Yaml specification require that [all keys are unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47670882/1609514)?

Comment: I manually wrote the above Yaml file without knowing about this specification and it shows the desired behaviour.

Comment: It is a shortcoming of a YAML processor to not report this YAML as invalid due to duplicate keys. Don't rely on it. PyYAML doesn't raise an error but when loading you will get only one of the two data sections.